# Set Timeout function and each function clash

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

The following code should trigger the mouse enter() and mouseleave() every each element in the found set with a 2000 ms gap between each one. The timeout is having no effect and it is going straight to the end.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var delayslide = 0;
    $(".featuredslider a").each(function(){
        var current = $(this).index();
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(".featuredslider a").mouseleave();
            $('.featuredslider a:eq(' + current + ')').mouseenter();
            delayslide += 2000;
        }, delayslide);
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
var elems = $( 'a', '.featuredslider' ).get(),
    i = -1;

(function loop() {
    $( elems[i] ).mouseleave();
    i += 1;
    $( elems[i] ).mouseenter();

    if ( i < elems.length ) { setTimeout( loop, 2000 ); }
})();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/G9VNj/

Comment: You shouldn't really name anonymous functions, and besides, there's a better approach... Let me write that out...

Comment: @ivans Oho, Zagrepčanin. `:)`

Comment: This is a sloppy organized code. I find there are better ways to do this.

Comment: @Shawn31313 What is sloppy? Please tell me how to improve it.